# Github PR is showing older commits

Tags: git, github

I created a github PR but it is showing older commits that are already merged. I had not fetched new changes before pushing, so did the merge from upstream and pushed that. Now it is showing the correct changes but still showing older commits. Is there a way to fix this without creating a new PR?

Have tried common solutions such as changing base etc

Comment: When you say "already merged", do you perhaps mean that the older commits were "squash merged" on top of your main branch?

Answer (score 0):

> common solutions such as changing base etc

Changing base (meaning rebase) should be the solution here: rebase your PR branch on top of your target branch, then force push.
That will:

- remove any old commits (already present in the target branch)
- update the existing PR branch.